# How to Remove Page From Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, url-rewrite

This is my website "http://www.vitaminf.ir/gosmart2/women/tops-women/hoodies-and-sweatshirts-women.html" i want to remove "gosmart2" from my url how can i achieve this. my site is "http://www.vitaminf.ir" but whenever i navigate through any category or product page it navigate as ""http://www.vitaminf.ir/gosmart2/category/category-type/product.html" how can i remove from my url "gosmart2"
your ans is appreciable for me

Answer (score 1):

If "gosmart2" is store code, then you need to do this.

You can disable store codes via admin from below path.

```
Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls > No
```

Run caching command after save configuration.

Comment: Hi Dhiren Vasoya, Thanks for ans my query. it i think "gosmart2" is not a store code but it's a template name. I'm new to magento & just start learning magento 2. my magento version is 2.1.6 kindly help me to rid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 magento installation in the server:

1. http://www.vitaminf.ir/gosmart2
2. http://www.vitaminf.ir/

Check both themes are different.

**OR**

You have 2 different websites under one magento installation. One is running http://www.vitaminf.ir/ and another one is running under subfolder with name gosmart2.

1. If there are 2 different installation then you need to copy the sub
   folder to root and change the urls in **core_config_data** to
   http://www.vitaminf.ir/.
2. If you are using one magento installation and run the website in sub
   folder then you need to change the default store run to root and
   change the url in **core_config_data** table.